# Распознавание прямоугольников Python OpenCV cv2

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, cv2

**Код:**

```py
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

hsv_min = np.array((0, 54, 5), np.uint8)
hsv_max = np.array((187, 255, 253), np.uint8)

fn = 'resistor_crop.jpg'  # имя файла, который будем анализировать
img = cv.imread(fn)

hsv = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)  # меняем цветовую модель с BGR на HSV
thresh = cv.inRange(hsv, hsv_min, hsv_max)  # применяем цветовой фильтр
_, contours0, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# перебираем все найденные контуры в цикле
for cnt in contours0:
    rect = cv.minAreaRect(cnt)  # пытаемся вписать прямоугольник
    box = cv.boxPoints(rect)  # поиск четырех вершин прямоугольника
    box = np.int0(box)  # округление координат
    cv.drawContours(img, [box], 0, (255, 0, 0), 2)  # рисуем прямоугольник

cv.imshow('contours', img)  # вывод обработанного кадра в окно

cv.waitKey()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Ошибка**

```
ERROR:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/My python project/findcolor/findline.py", line 14, in <module>
    _, contours0, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

hsv_min = np.array((0, 54, 5), np.uint8)
hsv_max = np.array((187, 255, 253), np.uint8)

fn = 'Qt.png'                               # имя файла, который будем анализировать
img = cv.imread(fn)

hsv = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)    # меняем цветовую модель с BGR на HSV
thresh = cv.inRange(hsv, hsv_min, hsv_max)  # применяем цветовой фильтр

# !!!
#_, contours0, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
(contours0, _) = cv.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# перебираем все найденные контуры в цикле
for cnt in contours0:
    rect = cv.minAreaRect(cnt)                      # пытаемся вписать прямоугольник
    box = cv.boxPoints(rect)                        # поиск четырех вершин прямоугольника
    box = np.int0(box)                              # округление координат
    cv.drawContours(img, [box], 0, (255, 0, 0), 2)  # рисуем прямоугольник

cv.imshow('contours', img)                          # вывод обработанного кадра в окно

cv.waitKey()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]